# Assemble a URL with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a base url,

```
var url = "/example/url/here"
```

and an object

```
var data = {"id": 1, "do": "some action"}
```

and I want to assemble a url with these to items in a similar fashion to how the $.get works, only I just want the url. Any ideas or do I have to loop through the object and assemble the url myself?

Comment: Can you expound on this a little more?  It is too vague for me this morning :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/):

```
url += '?' + $.param(data);
```

[**Try it here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3UT4/1/)

Comment: Thanks, I knew that there had to be something in jquery to accomplish assembling a query-string from an array

Answer (score 1):

```
$.param(data);
```

See:  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = url+'?'+$.param(data);
```

This returns `/example/url/here?id=1&do=some+action`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note that there were big changes between jQuery 1.3 and 1.4 in this library.  See the COMMENTS section of http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/ and http://benalman.com/news/2009/12/jquery-14-param-demystified/.  I'm not taking sides, but ASP apps are probably expecting the 1.3 behavior and PHP/Ruby probably expect 1.4, and there is a switch in 1.4 to make it act like 1.3, though not enabled by default.